# Show pop-up every friday and hide it after 24 hours

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a pop-up that I want to show on website every friday and hide it after 24 hours till next friday. Any idea?

Here is my code and fiddle:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.elem');
  
var current = new Date();
var expiry = new Date("April 26, 2019 08:00:00");

if ( current.getTime() >= expiry.getTime() ) 
{
  elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Will not work because you must check your comparison at a regular interval. Here, you are checking it at page load only.

Comment: 24 hours from when? Do you mean you want to show it for a rolling 24 hours after the visitor first sees it, or just during Friday? You want to hide it by default (with CSS) and only show it if the current day is Friday.

Comment: So you mean that when the user opens your app on a friday it should open the popup, regardless of the time. (Nothing on thursday and saturday)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check week day with function `getDay()`
0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday... 5 for Friday

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

var current = new Date();
var currentDay = current.getDay()

if (currentDay != 5 ) {
  elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check every so often, using a `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(checkTime, 60000);

function checkTime() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('.elem');

  var current = new Date();

  if ( current.getDay() != 5 && elem.style.display == "block" ) 
  {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
  else if ( current.getDay() == 5 && elem.style.display == "none" )
  {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

The second parameter is milliseconds between each check. I've used `60000`, which is one minute. Here are some common times:

```
Minutes | Milliseconds
--------|-------------
1:00    | 60000
2:00    | 120000
5:00    | 300000
10:00   | 600000
```